# Как в wp перевести все ссылки в относительные?

Tags: wordpress

Есть основной домен и есть его поддомен (прописаный алиас на хостинге) по сути они сюотображают 1 сайт. Как удалить из всех URL домен?

Answer (score 0):

Можно формировать домен сайта в wp-config.php

Например, вставить фрагмент

```
if ( isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) && ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) )
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = str_replace( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
        
$url_protocol = 'http://';       
        
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
        if ( 'on' == strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
            $url_protocol = 'https://';
        }

        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) {
            $url_protocol = 'https://';
        }
} elseif ( isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        $url_protocol = 'https://';
}        
         
$url = $url_protocol .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

define('WP_HOME',$url);

define('WP_SITEURL',$url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользовался вот таким решением:

```
define('WP_HOME',  "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}");
define('WP_SITEURL', "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}");
```

Для меня подошло идеально.